# xinput property 'Synaptics Noise Cancellation' doesn't exist - Thinkpad x220 - jittery touchpad - ubuntu18.04.3

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad, xinput

I just installed ubuntu on my thinkpad-x220 and my touchpad is extremely jittery / jumpy. If I don't touch it my mouse stays still which is fine, but once I start moving my finger on the touchpad the mouse shakes and moves which is so annoying.

Apparently this is a well known issue, but I'm not having any luck using the recomended solution of xinput:
http://x220.mcdonnelltech.com/ubuntu/#touchpad

When I run xinput I see this:

```
root@martin-ThinkPad-X220:~# xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I run this command:

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20
```

but get an error message saying:

```
root@martin-ThinkPad-X220:~# xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20

property 'Synaptics Noise Cancellation' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a working answer provided by Manfred Hampl (m-hampl) on this page:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/678600

"Your output shows that you can install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 without removing anything else.

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04`

I tried that and was able to install the synaptics drivers and then use the command

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20
```

This fixed the jumpy cursor problem I was experiencing.

Comment: I get an error saying `property 'Synaptics Noise Cancellation' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`